# How to change displayed value in dojox DropDownSelect

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have DropDownSelect declared with tags:

```
<select id="someId" dojoType="dojox.form.DropDownSelect" >
<option>Loading...</option>
</select>
```

Then when xhr load function is called I would like to remove the option above and create the new one "Choose Option", for example.

```
load: function(response) {
        //remove option, but it stays as displayedValue, displayed
        dojo.byId("someId").removeChild(dojo.byId("someId").lastChild); 
        //I would like to show the option below
        dijit.byId("someId").addOption({label: "Choose Option", value:"Select"});
        //dijit.byId("someId").setAttribute('displayedValue','Select'); // not working
        dijit.byId("someId").addOption(response); // add ajax options. 
        return response;
        },
```

Please, tell me how to show different option in DropDownSelect??? The version 1.3 is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//1. html: define drop down

```
<select id="ddselect" name="select" dojoType="dojox.form.DropDownSelect">
    <option value="none">
        Loading...
    </option>
</select>
```

// 2. onLoad handler:

```
    load: function(response) {
                    // get widget by id
        var dd = dijit.byId("ddselect");
        // remove loading option
                    dd.removeOption(0);
                    // add new option
        dd.addOption({ label: 'newValue1', value: 'nv1'});
                    // or add array of options
                    dd.addOption([{ label: 'newValue2', value: 'nv2' }, { label: 'newValue3', value: 'nv3'}]);
    }
```